# With NX/Angular, how can I debug an app production build failure?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I'm getting the following error, and I want to know how to debug it.

The command is `nx run my-app:build:production`

and the output includes (with a bunch of warnings omitted):

```
Error: Optimization error [main.64ff99fef94b1aca.js]: Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
main.64ff99fef94b1aca.js:22080:5: ERROR: Expected identifier but found "="
```

Now what I would like to do is to go to this main.js file at the line stated and make sense of what bit of the code is going wrong and where, however it doesn't exist in the `dist` folder so I can't even see where to begin?